# access variable from one class in another class in swift

Tags: ios, class, swift, variables

in my application I have a class called "Main" which creates a variable "cod" and assigns the value 0 to it, and within that class have buttons that are clicked, change the value of the variable "cod" and throw me to another layout that is accessed by another class. In this other class must access the value of variable changed by the button, but when I use the println to check the accessed value, it returns me the value 0 without the change. I'll post the code.

class Main: UIViewController {

var cod = 0

```
@IBAction func btnSp(sender: AnyObject) {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewConsultas") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    cod = 1

}
```

and in my another class

```
    var dados = Main().cod

    println(dados)
```

I'm doing something wrong to you can not change the value of the "cod" and access to other class?

Comment: where did you print the value in second class?

Answer (score 1):

`Main()` creates a **new** object, which means it isn't the same `Main` that you've been using to modify the variable.

You need to either pass your existing instance of `Main` to your other class or make the variable available somewhere that both classes can access (like a data model).

Comment: And see the discussion of this distinction (new instance vs. existing instance) in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECinstanceRefs